# How to create a random 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there any way of creating a 3D matrix randomly? There are ways to create random 2D matrices using [`randint`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35506-ant-colony-optimization-techniques-applied-on-travelling-salesman-problem/content/Codes/randint.m) function. Is there any inbuilt function like that?

E.g. a 4x4 matrix can be generated easily by using the `randint` function. What if I want to create a matrix of dimension 4x4x3?

Comment: Maybe create a 4x(4x3) = 4x12 matrix and reshape it so that its 4x4x3?

Comment: Note that the `randint` function is obsolete in MATLAB R2014a and may be removed in the future. As some answers stated, you can use `randi` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`randi(imax, size1, size2, size3)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) function where `imax` refers to maximum of random integer values (mean upper bound) and `1` is lower bound. You can expand `size` argument to `sizeN` what you want.

This is an example of its usage:

```
>> A = randi(5, 4, 4, 3)

A(:,:,1) =

     4     4     5     4
     4     1     2     2
     2     1     3     3
     4     3     2     4


A(:,:,2) =

     5     1     5     1
     5     2     2     2
     3     5     5     4
     1     2     2     3


A(:,:,3) =

     2     5     2     3
     5     2     3     4
     3     4     1     5
     3     4     1     1
```

Answer (score 7):

If you read the help carefully, you will notice that the [`randi`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) function accepts any number of dimensions.  You may do `randi(10,3,3,3)`

```
randi(10,3,3,3)

ans(:,:,1) =

     9    10     3
    10     7     6
     2     1    10


ans(:,:,2) =

    10    10     2
     2     5     5
    10     9    10


ans(:,:,3) =

     8     1     7
    10     9     8
     7    10     8
```